# In handleIncrement method, "this" is referring to undefined

Tags: reactjs

In the method `handleIncrement()` when I log "this" to console, it displays undefined.
Whereas `getBadgeclasses()` is also a method of the same class in which this refers to the parent class.
Why is it so? Is it because the `handleIncrement` method is called by onClick property or is there some other logic?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = { count: 2, tags: [] };

  handleIncrement() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleIncrement}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 bg-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;

    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no auto-binding of methods to itself,

You have 3 solutions(maybe more).

**First approach** by binding the method to itself.
create the following line inside a constructor:

```
this.handleIncrement= this.handleIncrement.bind(this);
```

**Second approach** refactor the onClick as the following:

```
onClick={()=>this.handleIncrement}
```

**Third approach** change the function to an arrow function

```
handleIncrement = (e) => {...}
```

then change the button aswell to:

```
onClick={this.handleIncrement.bind(this)}
```

This link will be use full:
[React & Autobinding](https://medium.com/komenco/react-autobinding-2261a1092849)

Comment: Thank you so much but why only handleIncrement is not binded to class? Whereas this is in formatCount is referring to the class. Both are methods of same class.

Comment: you are accessing a member from the class from the event handler.  this keyword is bound to depends on where it is defined. In this case, this reverts to its default binding. In the case where you are running in non-strict mode, this is the global window object, but in the case of strict mode, this is undefined. This answer can be found here: https://www.voitanos.io/blog/deal-with-undefined-this-react-event-handler-performant-way/